# Yii: renderPartial can't load view when using CAction

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to use the `renderPartial` method within a action class.

The method is unable to find the view.

The view is within the root of the app `/views/invoice/view.php`

```
<?php

class InvoiceAction extends CAction {

    public $invoice_id = 0;

    public function run() {
        Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial('/invoice/view');
    }

}
```

Comment: With //invoice/view works?

Comment: you could post it as a answer; its better than mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to the following code will work fine:

```
Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial('//invoice/view');
```

Answer (score 1):

Switched to the following code and it worked :

```
Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial('application.views.invoice.view');
```